# ClientSocketException (ClientException with SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: ...)

Tags: flutter, dart, http, email, qr-code

I'm beginner flutter developer, I have an issue working with the http package.
When I run my project, and [I click on button "envoyer"(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mid9p.jpg)
[I get the error below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRwfj.png)

My codes for this issue are:
**qrCodeController.dart file
**

```
import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/config/constants/ipadress.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class QRCodeController {
  Future<String> getQRCode(String email) async {
    String urlString = '$ipaddress/api/v1/qrCode?email=$email';
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(urlString));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // La requête a réussi, vous pouvez traiter la réponse ici
      String responseBody = response.body;
      return responseBody;
    } else {
      // La requête a échoué avec un code de statut autre que 200
      print('Échec de la requête : ${response.statusCode}');
      return "null";
    }
  }
}
```

**layoutLogin.dart file
**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/config/constants/color_theme.dart';
import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/controllers/qrCodeController.dart';
import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/modules/connexion/components/button.dart';
import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/modules/connexion/components/textInput.dart';
import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/modules/connexion/views/indexQR.dart';
import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/utils/provider.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class LayoutLogin extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const LayoutLogin({
    super.key,
    required this.formKey,
  });

  final formKey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final mailController = TextEditingController();

    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "Email",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .displayMedium
                    ?.copyWith(color: AppColor.primary80, fontSize: 25),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              Form(
                key: formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextInput(
                      icon: FontAwesomeIcons.envelope,
                      label: "Veuillez renseigner votre email",
                      placeholder: "Entre ton email",
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Veuillez saisir votre adresse e-mail';
                        }
                        final emailRegex =
                            RegExp(r'^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$');
                        if (!emailRegex.hasMatch(value)) {
                          return 'Veuillez saisir une adresse e-mail valide';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      controller: mailController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              DefaultButton(
                color: AppColor.primary80,
                text: "Envoyer",
                onPressed: () {
                  if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    QRCodeController qrCodeController = QRCodeController();
                    String email = ref.watch(inputValueProvider);
                    email = email.replaceAll('@', '%40');
                    qrCodeController.getQRCode(email).then((qrCodeData) {
                      if (qrCodeData != "") {
                        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const IndexQR()),
                          );
                        });
                      } else {
                        // La requête a échoué
                        print('La requête a échoué.');
                      }
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**ipadress.dart file**

```
const ipaddress = "http://192.168.1.67:8080";
```

Thanks for your help !

I have an issue working with the http package.
When I run my project, and [I click on button "envoyer"(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mid9p.jpg)
[I get the error below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRwfj.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, the MyHttpOverrides class that you provided is used to override the default behavior of the HTTP client, allowing you to customize the way HTTP requests are handled, including how SSL certificates are validated. This can be particularly useful in scenarios where you need to work with self-signed SSL certificates or when you want to ignore SSL certificate validation for development or testing purposes.

Add this class in your project,

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
```

then add this line in your main method.

```
HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
```

Add this two uses permission in AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

run this command on your terminal

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Then uninstall the app and install again.

Comment: Thanks for you help, but not working

Comment: @Mr_mido Please try again, I updated my answer and let me know if it's solved or not.
Thank you

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
After adding this line, app won't run at all. still facing the same error.